# Economics SE vs Quant SE?

Tags: discussion, topicality, close-reasons

Probably asked before but anyhoo thought of this from that: [English SE vs ELL SE?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5834/english-se-vs-ell-se)

Might I break any (site-specific) rule for asking questions here instead of Quant SE? Sure I could get better answers but let's say I don't care about that. Like is there anything on-topic Quant SE that is off-topic in Economics SE?

Answer (score 1):

If a question is off topic in Economics SE then it will obviously be closed by users/mods.

If the question is not off topic you can ask it here even if it would be better suited at Quant SE, but off topic questions are against our rules.

Comment: i mean to ask for an example. what's on-topic in quant SE that isn't here? like what's on-topic in stats SE that isn't in maths SE or in English SE that isn't in ELL SE?

Comment: @BCLC if that’s the only question you are asking why is this sentence in your question: “Might I break any (site-specific) rule for asking questions here instead of Quant SE?”

Comment: lol how can a question be on-topic on quant SE but off-topic in economics SE when quantitative finance is finance and when finance is economics? The only thing I can think of is maybe those soft questions or something.

Comment: @BCLC as long as you are writing your quant question in English, I recommend posting it on English SE! Except if it is about a theoretical scenario/model, then move it to Worldbuilding. You could also accept that some SEs have specialized.